# Вопросы касательно Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, распараллеливание

1)Моя программа использует для многопоточного копирования файлов цикл Parallel.ForEach.
Мне нужно вести статистику о том сколько файлов в данный момент скопировано.
Как это можно реализовать?

Я пробовал передавать в метод, который отвечает за копирование, переменную для подсчета количества, но так как копирование происходит в несколько потоков, то цифра считается некорректно.

2)Можно ли сделать как-нибудь контролировать какие элементы, какой поток берет?
К примеру первый поток берет каждый 1 элемент, второй каждый второй, третий каждый третий и т д?

Comment: Вы вообще уверены, что эту задачу имеет смысл распараллеливать? Насколько я знаю, при копировании файлов процессор практически не используется, и, следовательно, никакого эффекта от параллелизма не будет. Все "упрется" в диск.

Comment: Со статистикой проблем вообще нет, заведите общий счётчик и увеличивайте его (`Interlocked.Increment`, разумеется) в конце каждой итерации.

Comment: Контролировать, в принципе, можно. Для этого есть [`OrderablePartition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394988%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но может быть, вам достаточно [`MaxDegreeOfParalellism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @ VladD, MaxDegreeOfParalellism я уже использую в программе, однако по моим наблюдениям, если у меня 4 потока, то вся исходная коллекция поделится на 4 куска.

Comment: Копирование с диска на диск? Если да, то такие операции не стоит распараллеливать!

Comment: @Евгений Веприков ,На самом деле помимо копирования еще выполняется ресурсоемкий запуск приложения  через  process.start, который выполняет некоторые преобразования файлов. Я просто попытался как можно проще изложить.

Comment: У меня есть идея, имея массив путей к файлам, сгруппировать его по директориям и через foreach подавать эти директории в Parralel.foreach, что бы обработка в рамках одной папке, однако будет вероятность простоя, так как следующая директория не будет обрабатываться, пока все потоки не завершаться и как следствие, если массив закончится, то потоки будут ожидать другие потоки, что бы внешний foreach дал новую директорию на обработку. Нельзя ли в parallel.foreach засунуть структуру Очередь? Что бы коллекция не делилась, а обрабатывалась по принципу очереди?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заведите переменную-счетчик. Инкрементируйте ее после каждого
   копирования файла. Естественно, нужно позаботиться о синхронизации. Самый дешевый способ -- [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx).

   ```
   int filesCopied = 0;

   ...

   string[] files = ...;
   Parallel.ForEach(files, CopyFile);

   ...

   private void CopyFile(string file)
   {
      // код копирования
      Interlocked.Increment(ref filesCopied);
   }
   ```
2. Теоретически, если вы явно задаете опцию `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, можно создать [кастомный разделитель](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997411(v=vs.110).aspx), который разобьет входную последовательность на это же количество частей по заданному вами правилу. Но, во-первых, не гарантируется, что код будет исполняться, используя ровно MaxDegreeOfParallelism потоков. Во-вторых, зачем вам это, что вы хотите этим добиться? На первый взгляд вопрос кажется странным.

Comment: 1) Если копирование прервется, то будет легко найти место прерывания и продолжить копирование, так как все потоки обрабатывают близкие элементы коллекции.     2)допустим у меня есть 4 потока, 4 директории и в каждой директории по 10000 файлов. Скорее всего каждый поток возьмет по папки. Тогда папки будут копироваться одновременно и другие пользователи не смогут по мере завершения копирования работать с папками. Если бы потоки копировали бы файлы в пределах одной папки, то по завершению копирования папки, пользователи могли бы взять ее в работу, пока копируются остальные .

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь дешевый вариант в виде штатных методов? Сейчас у меня просто передается массив типа fileinfo. Мне что то типа: коллекция делится на куски по 50 элементов и каждый поток последовательно их извлекает. Это бы давало мне гарантию, что потоки работают рядом